# How to get text inside depth div tag with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the text content of the items inside the following 2 `div` elements. It work using absolute path:

```java
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='page-wrapper']/section/section/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[45]"));
data = element.getText();
System.out.println(data);
```

The text that I am trying to get is:

```
45
Se
Selenium
```

I am trying to get text using relative XPath, but it always fails.
I am trying use this combination:

```java
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'elemBox noclaim noclaim-tt') and contains(text(),'45')]"));
```

or

```java
 element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'elemBox noclaim noclaim-tt')]/div[contains(text(),'45')]"));
```

but still failed.

I have HTML code like this:

```xml
<div class="elemBox noclaim noclaim-tt text-right m-t-lg animated-add pulse-add animated pulse animated-add-active pulse-add-active" >
<div class="" ng-show="(filterTool(elementName.name)) || (name === '')">
    <div class="text-right ng-binding">45</div>
    <div class="text-left ng-binding">
        <span class="elemSym ng-binding">Se</span>
        <br/>
        Selenium              
    </div>
</div>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `contains(text(),'45')`, only the first direct-child text node will be evaluated. This is the reason you attempted XPath failed to find the `div`; because the text '45' is nested 2 levels from the outer `div` :

```
//div[contains(@class,'elemBox noclaim noclaim-tt') and contains(div/div/text(),'45')]
```

Or you might want to try using `.` instead of text to evaluate the entire texts within the outer `div` as opposed to evaluating only first direct-child text node  :

```
//div[contains(@class,'elemBox noclaim noclaim-tt') and contains(.,'45')]
```

Comment: I am trying //div[contains(@class,'elemBox noclaim noclaim-tt') and contains(.,'45')]
and it works. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't need to use `contains` word inside xpath.

```
textRightElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='elemBox noclaim noclaim-tt']/div[@class='text-right']"));
```

or if class `text-right` is unique, just use

```
textRightElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='text-right']"));
```

.... if you really need to find the element with it's value,

```
textRightElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='45']"));
```

Comment: I can't use only 'text-right' because 'text-right' is using on other div tag, 
and I can't only use [text()='45'] because element result only point to 45 beside I need all three : 45, Se and Selenium text.
Thanks for answer.